# Bad Searchview layout since upgrade of the different version

Tags: android

I upgraded my computer to android studio 2.1.1
I upgraded all build tools of android and now I use the 23.4.0 of appcompat-v7 / support-v4 / design

When I try to debug my software on my nexus 7 device (marschmallow) or galaxy s5 (lolipop) I have that strange layout
Does someone understand why ?

[image: problem with the searchview style]

My call of the searchview :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.machines, menu);


    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    return true;
}
```

and the xml resource :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

When I remove both theme, it has the same glich

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361076/nine-patches-are-broken-on-api-19-and-below/37377437#37377437

Comment: a huge thank you. I didn't find the find the keyword to find that issue.